# Como logro que las manecillas o agujas del reloj no retrocedan a su posición inicial en este reloj analógico?

Tags: javascript

Las agujas al completar la rotación vuelven retrocediendo a la posición inicial para comenzar un nuevo ciclo provocando un efecto que no esta bueno:

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector(".second-hand");
const minHand = document.querySelector(".min-hand");
const hourHand = document.querySelector(".hour-hand");

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondDegrees = (seconds / 60) * 360 + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDegrees}deg)`;

  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const minutesDegrees = (minutes / 60) * 360 + 90;
  minHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesDegrees}deg)`;

  const hours = now.getHours();
  const hoursDegrees = (hours / 24) * 360 + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hoursDegrees}deg)`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

```css
html {
  background: #018ded url(https://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=881&blur=5);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "helvetica neue";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.clock {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 3px #efefef,
    inset 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.clock-face {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-3px); /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.hand {
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 0.05s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>JS + CSS Clock</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="clock">
      <div class="clock-face">
        <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregué una variable que sirve de base para los grados de giro. Inicializada en 0, en el segundo 59 se incrementa en 360 para que la rotación continúe en base al giro anterior. Lo mismo para minutos y horas.

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector(".second-hand");
const minHand = document.querySelector(".min-hand");
const hourHand = document.querySelector(".hour-hand");

secondsBase = 0;
minutesBase = 0;
hoursBase   = 0;

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();

  const secondDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360 + 90) + secondsBase;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDegrees}deg)`;
  
  if(seconds == 59) secondsBase += 360;

  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const minutesDegrees = ((minutes / 60) * 360 + 90) + minutesBase;
  minHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesDegrees}deg)`;
  
  if(minutes == 59) minutesBase += 360;

  let hours = now.getHours();
  if(hours > 12) hours -= 12; // formato 12 horas
  const hoursDegrees = ((hours / 12) * 360 + 90) + hoursBase;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hoursDegrees}deg)`;
  
  if(hours == 11) hoursBase += 360;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

```css
html {
  background: #018ded url(https://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=881&blur=5);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "helvetica neue";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.clock {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 3px #efefef,
    inset 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.clock-face {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-3px); /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.hand {
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100%;

  transition: all 0.05s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>JS + CSS Clock</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="clock">
      <div class="clock-face">
        <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tiene un efecto raro la aguja de la hora

Comment: Quizás se debe a que estaba en formato 24 horas y en el reloj solo se muestran 12.